# Rejection and after that reapplication for the same opening?

Tags: rejection, applications

There was a job opening at a company relatively big, I took exams and I did pretty well and I gave an interview but no one was hired and the company after two weeks reannounce the job opening, exactly the same job opening. 
As an answer I took the following :

" blah blah
, but we would encourage you to further your knowledge and experience and you may apply again in the future for similar roles that are of interest to you."

As I wrote the company reannounces the position and the deadline is 2.5 months after the rejection. Simultaneously I am working by myself on a project relative to the position I applied for and I am expanding my knowledge.

So here is my question, do you believe I could reapply in such a short time or leave it for the future and get some more experience?

It looks bad and they might think I mock them? But on the other hand I learn and get experience (not work experience) and it might look positive.

Comment: @Erik Yes, I want to know if it looks bad or it looks good. So I will edit my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do you believe I could reapply in such a short time or leave it for the future and get some more experience?

Sure, you can reapply. The more interesting question would be, *does it make sense to reapply?* I think that's what you were getting at here:

> It looks bad and they might think I mock them? But on the other hand I learn and get experience (not work experience) and it might look positive

It's hard to answer that question without knowing more specifics, so instead of a specific yes or no answer, I think it makes sense to give you some guidelines.

**You need to base your reapplication timing on a reasonable time frame to acquire the skills you were missing the first time you applied.**

You mentioned that you have gotten more experience since the last time you applied, but we don't know if that experience fills the gap the employer was seeing in you. If they gave you specific feedback, you should reapply once you've closed that gap. For instance, if they were looking for someone with a specific certification that takes a month to achieve, and you've spent the last month getting it, then yes - reapply.

However, if they were looking for something more long-term, like *3+ years experience doing X* or *Masters degree in X or equivalent work experience* and you haven't achieved that - since it seems clear you couldn't have, given that those accomplishments take years and you're indicating it's only been a few months - then no, don't reapply.

**If it wasn't clear to you what the specific gap was that caused them to reject you the first time,** then it makes sense to reach out to them and ask for clarification. It's a reasonable question, it will show you're interested in not only the job but also in improving yourself, and it'll give you a specific goal to work towards.

In summary: It's not so much about how much time has passed, it's more about how much you've achieved in that time and whether or not it closes the gaps you had the first time.

Comment: I was wondering if I could send an email for feedback but I after I asked in plenty forums and here and I decided not to send an email for feedback. Do you believe that I should send?

Comment: If you can look at your own resume and interview, and compare it to the job description, and it's still not at all clear what they meant by "further your knowledge and experience" then yes - ask. However, if it's clear (ie they want specific things you don't have: a specific skill, X years of experience, a certain degree, etc) then no, don't ask.

Comment: Thank you very much for your specific advice, I have heard a lot about fear of the law about discrimination and I decided not to ....